# Java DateFormat.SHORT with full year

Tags: java, date

Is there any way to make [`DateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) format a date with a full year (eg. 12/12/2010), when using [`DateFormat.SHORT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#SHORT) as the pattern? I have to format dates in both en_US and da_DK.

I know I could use [`DateFormat.MEDIUM`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#MEDIUM), but the date have to be formatted using only numbers and separators, and `DateFormat.MEDIUM` for en_US produces something like 'Dec 12, 2010'.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If both formats are the same, then simply use:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

If they differ:

```
private static Map<Locale, String> formats = new HashMap<Locale, String>();

static {
    formats.put(new Locale("en_US"), "MM/dd/yyyy");
    formats.put(new Locale("da_DK"), "dd.MM.yyyy");
}
```

And then instead of using `DateFormat.getDateInstance(..)` use

```
new SimpleDateFormat(formats.get(locale)).format(..);
```

Comment: They differ in the separators, and the month and date parts are switched. But I like this solution! :)

Comment: Is there a more generalized solution for this, especially in cases where you want to be able to support *all* locales?

Comment: @cloudymusic can you unambiguously parse 8/9/10 across all locales?  Is it:  September 10, 2008?  September 8, 2010?  August 9, 2010?

Answer (score 6):

## java.time

You can use the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes that supplant the old date-time classes. Instead of [`DateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html), use a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) derived from a [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html).

`DateTimeFormatterBuilder` can provide a pattern that can be used with `DateTimeFormatter`. Using [`String.replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) you can insert `yyyy` instead of `yy` in the [FormatStyle.SHORT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html#SHORT) date pattern:

```
        String pattern =
            DateTimeFormatterBuilder
                .getLocalizedDateTimePattern
                    ( FormatStyle.SHORT
                    , null
                    , IsoChronology.INSTANCE
                    , locale
                    );
        pattern = pattern.replace("yy", "yyyy");
        DateTimeFormatter dtf =
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);
```

Comment: Clever answer. The only problem I see is that it assumes that for every possible locale, the `FormatStyle.SHORT` style *always* uses two digits for year. If one were to use 4 digits, this approach would break.

Comment: @BasilBourque Using `pattern.replace("yyyy", "yy").replace("yy", "yyyy")` will solve your '4 digits problem'.

Comment: @irieill Should also replace any `u` as well as `y`, the other year-designator code. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just use FormatStyle.MEDIUM ?

Answer (score 3):

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Data_Type_How_to/Legacy_Date/Display_the_year_in_full_four_digits_when_using_localization.htm

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, locale);
    if (df instanceof SimpleDateFormat) {
      SimpleDateFormat sdf = (SimpleDateFormat) df;
      // To show Locale specific short date expression with full year
      String pattern = sdf.toPattern().replaceAll("y+", "yyyy");
      sdf.applyPattern(pattern);
      return sdf.format(cal.getTime());
    }
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).